# defining variables inside a function belonging to a class

Tags: python, class

In a code, there is a class that has a function named 'goal_callback'. In the function, variables are defined using .init prefix and others are defined normally without the prefix. 
I know that the self. prefix is used to make the variable a 'class variable' so that it can be accessible to every function in class. So in the code, I have, only one function present, does it make any difference if we define the variables with the self. prefix or not. 
What exactly will be the difference between the '_pub_takeoff' variable and the 'takeoff_or_land' variable?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

class CustomActionMsgClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._as = actionlib.SimpleActionServer("action_custom_msg_as", CustomActionMsgAction, 
    self.goal_callback, False)
  def goal_callback(self, goal): 
    success = True
    r = rospy.Rate(1)
    self._pub_takeoff = rospy.Publisher('/drone/takeoff', Empty, queue_size=1)
    self._takeoff_msg = Empty()
    self._land_msg = Empty()
    # Get the goal word: UP or DOWN
    takeoff_or_land = goal.goal #goal has attribute named 'goal'. 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 rospy.init_node('action_custom_msg')
 CustomActionMsgClass()
 rospy.spin()
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation / code for `rospy`.

Comment: The knowledge about .init prefix - where does it cones from? I mean, I never heard of that.

Comment: What prefix are you talking about? `_takeoff_msg` is an instance variable: an attribute of the object `self`. `takeoff_or_land` is just a function-local variable unrelated to any particular object. The leading `_` in some of the attribute names is just a convention that signals the attribute shouldn't be accessed directly outside of one of the class's methods (it's not part of the public interface to the class).

Comment: I made a mistake in naming the prefix, it was 'self.' not '.init', I corrected the question though. Thanks, @chepner for ur comment, it helped me understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for object-level and class-level variables.

```py
class A(object):
    Z = 3  # class variable. Upper-case is good code style for class-level variables
           # defined inside the class but outsize of it's methods
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1  # object variable
        y = 2       # local variable; it will lost after returning from the function
    def some_method(self):
        self.w = 4  # object variable too
        # Note that it is not recommended to define
        # object variables outside of __init__()
```

In your code `_pub_takeoff` is variable of the object;  `takeoff_or_land` is local variable.